# Angular Close Slide in Panel When Click Outside

Tags: angular

I have a simple component with the job of sliding in as an overlay from the right side and covering 40% of the screen. How do I make it disappear when the user clicks outside of it?

**side-overlay.component.html**

```
<div class="sidebar-layout sidebar" [class.open]="open">
    <ng-content />
</div>
```

**side-overlay.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'datona-side-overlay',
    templateUrl: './side-overlay.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./side-overlay.component.scss'],
})
export class SideOverlayComponent {
    @Input() open: Boolean = false;
}
```

**side-overlay.component.scss**

```
.sidebar-layout {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar.open {
    width: 40%;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use [ng-click-outside](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-click-outside)? However I see that it's no longer maintained, but there are a ton of forks [like this one](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-click-outside) ([NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mintplayer/ng-click-outside))

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the click event outside of your component is to use the `document` and listen for clicks there. If the click happens on an element different from the sidebar, then close it

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
onDocumentClick(event: MouseEvent) {
  const sidebarElement = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
  if (!sidebarElement.contains(event.target)) {
    this.open = false;
  }
}
```

Another way would be to handle this behavior outside this component, on the level of the parent. You have two divs, one for the sidebar and one for the content of the page. If the user clicks on the content div then update the `open` attibute to `false`

```
// in parent component html
<div>
  <app-side-overlay [open]="isSidebarOpen"></app-side-overlay>
</div>
<div (click)="handleContentClick()">
  <!-- page content here -->
</div>

// in parent component .ts
isSidebarOpen: boolean = true;

handleContentClick() {
  this.isSidebarOpen = false;
}
```

Depends on the way you want your app structured, I would personally go with the second way.

Comment: Are you sure removeEventListener will do anything? I'm afraid bound functions will never be identical when created separately…

Comment: might be risky, i changed it to hostlistener. Might not even need to use `document.querySelector` in this case, maybe the event has the info already

Answer (score 0):

You could use a curtain like so:

**side-overlay.component.html**

```
<div class="sidebar-layout sidebar" [class.open]="open">
  <div>HELLO</div>
</div>
<div class="curtain" (click)="closeSidebar()"></div>
```

**side-overlay.component.scss**

```html
.sidebar-layout {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.3s;
    background: maroon;
}

.sidebar.open {
    width: 40%;
}

.curtain {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

**side-overlay.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'datona-side-overlay',
  templateUrl: './side-overlay.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-overlay.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @Input() open: Boolean = true;

  closeSidebar() {
    this.open = false;
  }
}
```